# How to apply conditional format to odt file?

Tags: libreoffice, odt, libreoffice-writer

I need to evaluate a cell on a table on a odt, file, and apply conditional format if value is > 0.
Not in speedsheet, is for writer

Comment: You can insert a LO Calc table into Writer, giving you all Calc features inside a odt document, including conditional formatting. Would this be a viable solution for you?

Comment: I insert a table into the odt file, but where is the menu form conditional formatting? I search everywhere

Comment: If you're inside the Calc spreadsheet object, check the "Format" menu: it should contain the "conditional formatting" entry. Those calc-specific entries are visible only if the Calc OLE object is active, so you may need to double-click on the object first to activate it. I've tested this with LO 5.4 on Win 10.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with LO 5.4 and 6.0.4 on Win 10:

IMHO, the best solution is to insert a LO Calc spreadsheet as "OLE Object" into the odt file. This gives you the complete Calc funtionality inside Writer.

To do so, put the cursor to where the table should appear. Select Menu "Insert" -> "Object" -> "OLE Object". In the following window, select "New" and "LibreOffice 6.0 Spreadsheet". Alternatively, you may insert an already-existing Calc table.

After clicking OK, the object will appear, and it's already activated (you can determine if it's active by the thick gray border and the row/column heads - you can "deactivate" it by clicking outside, anywhere in the Writer document; you can re-activate the Calc object by double-clicking inside its borders).

Now, you can edit the Calc table as usual. Notice that the Menus will adapt to the Calc features if the Calc OLE object is active. So, e.g. the "Format" Menu will only contain a "Conditional formatting" entry if the Calc OLE object is active.

Here are some screenshots:

1. Insert a OLE object in Writer:

[image]

2. Writer document with embedded Calc table:

[image: description]

3. Applying conditional formatting to some content of the embedded Calc sheet:

[image]

4. Resulting Writer document with conditionally-formatted Calc table (Calc object is active):

[image]

5. Same as 4, now Calc object is inactive:

[image]